# Can I specify styling for specific lines in css?

Tags: css

Is there any way to apply css formatting to just the first (or nth) line of text in CSS?
Suppose I have:

```
<h2>This is a line of text on my web page</h2>
```

That gets displayed as:

## This is a line of text
on my web page

Is there a way to specify, a priori, separate formatting for the first and second lines without knowing where the line break will occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only the `:first-line` pseudo-element; there isn't any for the second, third, fourth, ... nth lines.

```
h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: blue;
}

h2:first-line {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: There is only one colon… not two. Even in pseudo-elements. :)

Comment: @Shi: You might want to read [the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements). I reduced them to a single colon to be nice to IE < 9.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about that difference between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements yet.

Comment: @Shi: Note that `:first-line` is still alright in CSS3 - the only difference is IE. (Always IE.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:first-line selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo) (CSS2) or [::first-line selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line) (CSS3).

```
h2:first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```